# How should we tag Lost in Space (2018) questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

As many of us are already aware, Netflix recently rebooted *Lost in Space*, but it seems we're still using the old [lost-in-space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space) tag for the new show.  While the shows obviously have a number of substantial parallels, they are very clearly set in distinct continuities.  I think we need a new tag.

I wanted to ask a question about the 2018 reboot, so I tagged it with [lost-in-space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space)[lost-in-space-2018](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-2018), because I thought that was approximately right.  **Should we use both tags, or just the more specific tag?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose we use the following tags for the (now 20) questions we have.

- [lost-in-space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space) for all questions in the franchise.
- [lost-in-space-1965](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-1965) or alternatively [lost-in-space-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-tos) for the 1960s original.
- [lost-in-space-1998](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-1998) for the film, should any questions ever arise about it.
- [lost-in-space-2018](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-2018) for the new series on Netflix.

In line with how other tags are used, [lost-in-space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space) should be used on all questions.
Any questions about additional materials, such as the comics or the novel, can fall under the general franchise tag, unless they become too numerous, in which case they should get their own tags, such as [lost-in-space-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-comics) or [lost-in-space-novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-novel).

Comment: I support this. It follows our conventions and it's easy to apply to the limited questions we have. Plus `lost-in-space-2018` is already a tag, so it's clear it's a new work. This can be done ASAP, since it follows our standards.

Comment: I've started retagging the remaining [lost-in-space-1965] accordingly, and will finish later if someone else doesn't do it first.

Comment: @CreationEdge I've done some too, as you may have noticed. I've added and updated usage guidance on the tags as well.

Comment: I believe this is done now.